# Return multiple columns from subquery as Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my data.

```
Products: <Where all list of SKU are stored>
Prod_ID | Prod_Desc      | Base_Unit_ID
1       | Custom Product | 1

UOM: <Masterlist for Unit of measures>
UOM_ID | Desc
1      | Piece
2      | Box
3      | Case

UOM_Conversion: <From base unit. Multiplier is how many base unit in a To_Unit>
Prod_ID | from_Unit_ID | Multiplier | To_Unit_ID
1       | 1            | 100        | 2
1       | 1            | 400        | 3
```

Given This Data. How Can I display it like this?

```
Product        | Base Unit | Pack Unit | Multiplier | Case Unit | Multiplier
Custom Product | Piece     | Box       | 100        | Case      | 400
```

I have tried Left Join Lateral but sadly. What it does is return two rows.

The reason I want to do this is because Im developing a module which stores products with multiple Unit of measure(Max of 3). So I dont want to create 3 columns of Unit, Pack and Case hence the reason I created the UOM_conversion table.

Comment: Do you really need this information in a single row?

Comment: Yes. I need it in one row. As I will be displaying multiple products in a grid and want the user to view everything with a single glance.

Comment: What if you have ten or a hundred rows in `uom_conversion` for that product?

Comment: @Bigboss It smells like bad modelling. You shouldn't constraint the query results to the data visualization. The query is actually a very simple one, but in order for the database to return all data in a single row, your query will become very complex, inflexible and pron to errors. Imho you should get the data in multiple rows and do what you want in UI.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Each product will have 3 UOM conversion entry at all times.

Comment: @JimJones Any suggestions on how should I model my database?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a global misconception here but I will give you it after the solution for your problem. I advise you to look at it.

So firstly : what you need here is the crosstab() function.

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

For the following script :

```
create table uom
(
    uom_id int primary key
    , description varchar (250)
);

create table products 
(
    prod_id int primary key
    , prod_desc varchar(250)
    , base_unit_id int references uom (uom_id)
);

create table uom_conversion 
(
    prod_id int references products (prod_id)
    , from_unit_id int references uom (uom_id)
    , multiplier int
    , to_unit_id int references uom (uom_id)
);

insert into uom values (1, 'Piece'), (2, 'Box'), (3, 'Case');
insert into products values (1, 'Custom Product', 1);
insert into uom_conversion values (1,1,100,2), (1,1,400,3);
```

The request is :

```
select 
    p.prod_desc as "Product"
    , u.description as "Base Unit"
    , u2.description as "Pack Unit"
    , final_res."1" as "Multiplier"
    , u3.description as "Case Unit"
    , final_res."2" as "Multiplier"
from crosstab(
'select 
    p.prod_id
    , base_unit_id
    , multiplier
from products p
    inner join uom_conversion uc
        on uc.prod_id = p.prod_id')
        as final_res (prod_id int, "1" int, "2" int)
    inner join crosstab('select 
    uc.prod_id
    , u.description
    , uc.to_unit_id
from uom_conversion uc
    inner join uom u
        on u.uom_id = uc.to_unit_id') 
        as final_res_2 (prod_id int, "Box" int, "Case" int)
    on final_res.prod_id = final_res_2.prod_id
    inner join products p
    on p.prod_id = final_res.prod_id
    inner join uom u
    on p.base_unit_id = u.uom_id
    inner join uom u2
    on u2.uom_id = final_res_2."Box"
    inner join uom u3
    on u3.uom_id = final_res_2."Case";
```

This is solving your problem. BUT : How do you know the order of what is pack_unit and what is the case_unit? I think from this question a lot more will come up.

Comment: I forgot to include the level in UOM Coversion. Anyway.I tried crosstab and just couldn't get the right query. Will try your solution and try its speed. Thanks a lot!.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to change your modelisation anyway. Could you update your post with your business requirements? (like for example what is an uom, why do you need it, what is 'multiplier' for? ... etc.) At first sight I think you need some self references and recursive query to do what you apparently want.